# How do you prevent line breaks in generated components in Angular 4/2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a generated component by Angular 4 inside of 'white-space: pre-wrap' span, so I don't want any line extra line breaks that I didn't ask for.  Does anybody have any idea how to prevent them from being generated?  I typically use comments to surround html to ensure no line breaks show up, but when a component is automatically generated it seems like I have no control over it and line breaks are generated along with the component.

```
<span style="white-space: pre-wrap"><!--
  --><app-gen-component></app-gen-component><!--
--></span>
```

Comment: What do you mean by extra line breaks? Also, what is the component that you're seeing this in? Is the styling there with some sort of margin you don't want? You have checked the DOM and found out what's going on with the unwanted space?

Comment: I figured it out, it wasn't an issue in CSS or Angular, it was my IDE which kept on inserting new lines after I saved the component template file.

Answer (score 1):

This wasn't an issue in Angular or CSS, but and issue with my IDE.  My IDE kept on persisting on adding a new line after I saved the component template file.